# SQL to Parse a Key-Value String

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I have a comma delimited string like this:

```
key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3,key1=value1.1,key2=value2.1,key3=value3.1
```

and I'd like to parse it into a table that looks like this:

```
Key1       Key2       Key3
==============================
value1     value2     value3
value1.1   value2.1   value3.1
```

I'm able to split the string into rows:

```
ID      Data
================
1       key1=value1
2       key2=value2
3       key3=value3
...
```

but I get stuck there and can't seem to figure out a way to do the rest. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this all in SQL, or doing some processing in code and uploading it to the database?

Comment: This seems to be almost the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034299/stored-procedure-to-parse-a-string). However, since TSQL is a very weak language for text manipulation and parsing, I would do it in another language if at all possible.

Comment: @cost, yes, the input to the stored procedure is the delimited string and the output is the table

Comment: In your final result, what dictates that `value2` should be in the same row as `value1` as opposed to the row with `value1.1`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @ErikE, this is SQL 2008. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to get your data into the one key/value pair per row format, then much of the work is done.  Let me call that result `t`.  Something like this might get you the rest of the way:

```
select max(case when LEFT(data, 4) = 'key1' then SUBSTRING(data, 6, len(data)) end) as key1,
       MAX(case when LEFT(data, 4) = 'key2' then SUBSTRING(data, 6, len(data)) end) as key2,
       MAX(case when LEFT(data, 4) = 'key2' then SUBSTRING(data, 6, len(data)) end) as key3
from t
group by (id - 1)/3
```

This assumes that the `id` is assigned sequentially, as shown in your example.

Comment: This is great. I think what I missed was the group by clause. Thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generic version that does not rely on sequential Ids. However, what isn't clear is how say `value1`, `value2` in your final result are related to each other instead of `value1`, `value2.1`. In this solution, I arbitrarily sequenced each occurrence of a given key.

```
With SplitKeyValuePairs As
    (
    Select Id
        , Left([Data], CharIndex('=', [Data]) - 1) As KeyName
        , Substring([Data], CharIndex('=', [Data]) + 1, Len([Data])) As Value
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By Left([Data], CharIndex('=', [Data]) - 1) Order By Id ) As RowNum
    From SplitDelimitedString
    )
Select Max ( Case When KeyName = 'Key1' Then Value End ) As [Key1]
    , Max ( Case When KeyName = 'Key2' Then Value End ) As [Key2]
    , Max ( Case When KeyName = 'Key3' Then Value End ) As [Key3]
From SplitKeyValuePairs
Group By RowNum
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3233/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, too:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         Grp = ID / 3,
         KeyName = Left(Data, CharIndex('=', Data) - 1),
         Value = Substring(Data, CharIndex('=', Data) + 1, 8000)
      FROM
         SplitString
   ) S
   PIVOT (Max(Value) FOR KeyName IN (Key1, Key2, Key3)) P
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is really old, but leaving this here just in case someone might find this useful or appropriate for their specific parsing requirement.

```html
-- =============================================
-- Author: Peter Gumpal
-- Create date: October 23, 2018
-- Description: This function was developed to transform a key-value pair delimited string into a table.
--usage as follows:
-- Select * from dbo.KVParser('LP=pH FM=(begin)[odor](add)[odor](end) US=pgumpal')
-- this will return 3 records containing keys: LP, FM and US. Between "=" are values so  if the string
-- used is a CSV, the comma character will not be omitted. 
-- Key limitation: Fixed to two characters, update code as required.
-- Note: Code not optimal, suggestions/mods are always welcome. - Peter :)
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[KVParser] 
(
@pKVString varchar(500)
)
RETURNS  @kvtemp table ([key] varchar(2), [val] varchar(300))
AS
Begin
Declare @str varchar(500)

set @str = @pKVString -- 'LP=pH FM=(begin)[odor](add)[odor](end) US=pgumpal'
Declare @curKey varchar(2)
Declare @curChar varchar(1)
Declare @concatStr varchar(300)
Declare @ctrI int
Set @ctrI = 0
While (len(@str) > @ctrI)
Begin
 Set @curChar = SUBSTRING(@str,@ctrI,1)
 If (@curChar = '=')
  Begin
   Set @curKey = SUBSTRING(@str, @ctrI - 2 ,2) --get the key
    --begin, get value from its right side
    Set @ctrI = @ctrI + 1
    Set @curChar = SUBSTRING(@str,@ctrI,1)
    Set @concatStr = ''
    --loop into the value
    While (@curChar <> '='AND len(@str)  >= @ctrI)
     Begin
      Set @curChar = SUBSTRING(@str,@ctrI,1)
      Set @concatStr = isnull(@concatStr,'') + ISNULL(@curChar,'')
      Set @ctrI = @ctrI + 1
     End
       --end, get value from its right side

   Insert into @kvtemp([key],[val])
    Select @curKey, LEFT(@concatStr, IIF(RIGHT(@concatStr,1)= '=', len(@concatStr)-3,len(@concatStr)))
    --above IIF was added to trim the closing key and = / line needs improvement. 
   Set @ctrI = @ctrI - 3 --decrement counter to 3 to back read the key for the closing =
  End
 Set @ctrI = @ctrI + 1
End
Return
End
```